How does Meshlab actually do edge decimation
When using meshlab, if one selects the decimation operation a textbox opens up saying:

Simplify a mesh using a quadric based edge-collapse strategy. A variant of the well known Garland and Heckbert simplification algorithm with different weighting schemes to better cope with aspect ration and planar/degenerate quadrics areas.
See:
M. Garland and P. Heckbert.
Surface Simplification Using Quadric Error Metrics (pdf)
In Proceedings of SIGGRAPH 97.

But it does not describe what the differences actually are. My questions are:

What data structure does meshlab use? Is it a radial edge or something else?
What are the different schemes it uses for weights that deal with aspect ratio and planar regions?
How does it deal with non-manifold regions?


Regarding your second point: in the original paper by Garland & Heckbert, the cost of contracting a pair of vertices/an edge (v1, v2) is the sum of squared distances between the newly created vertex v_bar (that replaces the edge) and the planes of the triangles that meet at v1 and v2.
Now MeshLab relies on VCGlib for most of its computations. You can find details about the implementation of the edge collapse algorithm here. Basically it rescans the faces after the (simulated) collapse and uses a penalty if newly created triangles have an aspect ratio under a certain threshold and if their normals vary more than another threshold.
I'm not sure I understand your other questions, but my understanding is that the algorithm just considers the mesh connectivity (which is quite easy to get whether the mesh is stored as a face-vertex list or another format such as winged edge) and just works as long as there is an edge connecting two vertices.

"Just considers the edge connectivity"
This is not as easy as it sounds. Meshlab handles non-manifold geometry. And thus it is not using a winged edge nor half edge.
Next, you have a multiplicity of cases, how does it handle degenerate colinear triangles, how does it handle collapsing an edge with no incident triangles, how does it handle collapsing non-manifold edges, how does it handle collapsing an edge in a tetrahedron...
There's a myriad of edge cases that need to be taken into account for a robust implementation. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Regarding your 1st point: the face-vertex representation is the most used in computer graphics if I'm not mistaken and the TriEdgeCollapseQuadric class of VCGLib contains a VertexIterator and a FaceIterator so there's a good chance that it uses that representation too. But what I meant is that the algorithm should work as long as a list of vertex pairs is provided, disregarding how this list has been populated.

Regarding yout 3rd point: as illustrated in the original paper (Figure 2) the algorithm can also contract non-connected vertices. Also the conclusion of the paper states that "our system is quite capable of handling and simplifying non-manifold objects". My guess is that as a "good connectivity" is not a requirement the algorithm just proceeds to collapse the provided vertex pairs.
